# iOS determine the number of touches

Tags: ios, numbers, touch

In my app i need to know if the user is touching with two fingers or only one. 
How can i do this?. I have this code that works, but i only get where is the touch. How can i determine how many fingers are touching the view?

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
      NSLog(@"touch at %@", NSStringFromCGPoint([touch locationInView:touch.view]));
      return YES;
}
```

Need help please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In your target's action selector, you'll have access to `[gesture numberOfTouches]`.

```
UIGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myResponder:)];

- (void)myResponder:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
  [gesture numberOfTouches];
}
```

Comment: I tried but still not working. Is not calling the selector. Are you sure is has to be the UIGestureRecognizer class?

Comment: I used the superclass `UIGestureRecognizer` as an example because you didn't post which subclass you were using. Is your gesture recognizer added to a `UIView`?